# How to (programmatically) figure out the path of the current ArcMap document with VBA

Tags: vba, arcgis, esri, arcmap

I would like a Visual Basic for Application Function which shows the path of the current document.

For example if ArcMap is displaying `map.mxd` I need to display its path.

I found only some examples for querying the path of the datasources of the displayed layers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
Dim DocAbsPath As String
DocAbsPath = Application.Templates.Item(Application.Templates.Count - 1)
```

Taken from [this](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=992&t=299025) thread.